# Set of optimal directions is a cone

Tags: linear-programming

Let $\vec{u}$ be an optimal point for the linear programming problem:
\begin{equation}
\min{ \vec{c}^T \vec{x}}\\
\text{s.t. } A\vec{x}=\vec{b} \text{ and } \vec{x} \geq \vec{0}
\end{equation}

where $A\in M_{m\times n}$, $\vec{c}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\vec{b}\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

We said that $\vec{d}$ is an *optimal direction at $\vec{u}$* if there exist some $\varepsilon > 0 $ such that $\vec{u} + \varepsilon\vec{d}$ is also an optimal solution. Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ the set of optimal direction at $\vec{u}$. Prove that $D$ is a cone. That is, for any $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2,\ldots\vec{x}_k \in D$, we must show that

> $\{\alpha_1\vec{x}_1 +\alpha_2\vec{x}_2 + \cdots + \alpha_k\vec{x}_k \text{ | } \alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}\text{ , }\alpha_i\geq0\}\subseteq D.$

Note: It might help the fact that the set of optimal solutions of such LP problem is a convex set. Also, we may assume that an optimal value is always in the feasible set of constraints.

### Proof Sketch

We must show that the conic combination of $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2,\ldots\vec{x}_k \in D$ is an optimal direction at $\vec{u}$. That is, there exists some  $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$\vec{u}+ \varepsilon (\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \vec{x}_i)$$ is also an optimal.
Since every $\vec{x}_i$ is an optimal direction at $\vec{u}$ then there exist some $\varepsilon_i>0$ such that $\vec{u}+\varepsilon_i\vec{x}_i$ is an optimal.

My struggle until this point is that i cannot see the conection between the $\varepsilon$ that I need to find and the other $\varepsilon_i$ that I already have.

Comment: But what have you tried?

Comment: Actually, I tried to find the relationship between the fact that convex combination of optimal solution is also optimal and the $\varepsilon$. But that wasn't useful.

Comment: Try to make it feasible first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction, it suffices it suffices to show that if $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2 \in D$ and $a_1, a_2\geq 0$ then $a_1\vec{x}_1+a_2\vec{x}_2 \in D$. If either $a_1$ or $a_2$ is $0$ then the problem is trivial. We therefore suppose without loss of generality that $a_1, a_2>0$.

To prove this, we let $\varepsilon_1>0$ and $\varepsilon_2>0$ be such that $\vec{u}+\varepsilon_1\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{u}+\varepsilon_2\vec{x}_2$ are optimal points for your linear program. The fact that such numbers $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ exists follows from the assumption that $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2\in D$.

Since the collection of optimal solutions for the linear program forms a convex set, we know that for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$,
$$
\lambda\left(\vec{u}+\varepsilon_1\vec{x}_1\right) + (1-\lambda)\left(\vec{u}+\varepsilon_2\vec{x}_2\right) = \vec{u} + \lambda\varepsilon_1 \vec{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\varepsilon_2\vec{x}_2
$$
is also an optimal point. Therefore, in order to prove that $a_1\vec{x}_1+a_2\vec{x}_2 \in D$, it suffices to find $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and some $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
\vec{u} + \varepsilon \left(a_1\vec{x}_1+a_2\vec{x}_2\right)
=\vec{u} + \lambda\varepsilon_1 \vec{x}_1 + (1-\lambda)\varepsilon_2\vec{x}_2.
$$
We thus seek $\lambda\in [0,1]$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
\varepsilon a_1 = \lambda \varepsilon_1,\quad \varepsilon a_2 = (1-\lambda) \varepsilon_2.
$$
After solving for $\varepsilon$ and $\lambda$, we are done.